# (How) can I burn a 1080p video to DVD5 (not BluRay)?

Tags: video, dvd, burning, 1080p

I've been stuck on this for a few days now.
A friend of mine wants to have a movie burned on DVD and she doesn't have a BluRay player. Obviously, I want the movie to be of the highest resolution. I've read on several places that it is possible to burn 1080p videos to regular DVD5's. These can't be played by regular DVD players but my friend has a laptop which she will be using to watch the movie on.
Now I've tried several programs to try and put this 1080p movie on a disc. I've tried:

- Wondershare Uniconverter
- Leawo Prof. Media
- NCH Videopad
- Wondershare DVD Creator
- Roxio Creator

These programs can burn my movie to the DVD, but they will always scale it down to standard PAL definition (720x576). In Leawo Prof. Media there is an option for 1080p video but its only listed under the BluRay formats. I'm starting to wonder if 1080p is, in fact, exclusive to BluRay. But then again, I've read from several different sources that it is possible to put it on regular DVD5's.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this and/or does anyone have a way of achieving this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The DVD video standard doesn't just apply only to the physical media,
it also applies to the video and audio format and compression technique.
In a DVD, the video has to be compressed with MPEG-2,
which is ancient and inefficient compared to modern codecs.

You may transcode a HD video to fit on DVD5 or DVD9 with h.264
(or better yet, h.265) and it would look indistinguishable from a 25GB bluray,
but it wouldn't play in most DVD players because it wouldn't conform to the
standards they were built for.
The DVD standard is limited to MPEG-2 video at 720x480.

You may use a video product to transcode the video to a file that would fit
on a **data DVD** and play it from DVD as a file,
not using it as a playable DVD.
An example product that can do such transcoding is the free [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

You may also use the free
[BDRebuilder](https://www.videohelp.com/software/BD-Rebuilder)
to create a playable DVD, but it also requires to be installed the products of
ffdshow, Haali Media Splitter and avisynth, which you might prefer not to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can try free [AnyBurn](http://www.anyburn.com/).

That said, **in what file format** is the video? If you use a standard format such as MP4 or AVI, the file should be written *verbatim* (no pun intended), and play *exactly* as does the original. Almost all computers, "smart" televisions and tablets can display those two formats. If you need to do so, there are numerous tools to convert media to other formats, such as free application [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) and free, context-menu tool, [FileConverter](https://github.com/Tichau/FileConverter).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. The video is in .mkv format. I'm assuming you are reffering to the H.264 encoding? I will try AnyBurn. Thanks!